# How to count rows of pivot table where value is greater than 0

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, excel, excel-interop

I have a SQL view that returns rows containing a couple of "value" columns. For the sake of simplicity, let's call them `AmountA`, `AmountB` and `AmountC`.

I'm using a pivot table in Excel to create a report for that data. The source range of the pivot table is generically generated using .Net reflection, then pushed to Excel using Excel Interop. The pivot table is also dynamically generated/configured using Excel Interop.

I need to calculate and display a field that will count the number of rows where `AmountA` is greater than 0. I also need to do the same for `AmountB` and `AmountC`. The result should be displayed in the pivot table, on the same row level, in the following order : `AmountA` - `CountA` - `AmountB` - `CountB` - `AmountC` - `CountC`. To better understand what I'm trying to accomplish, think about a pivot table field summarized by count, but with a behavior similar to the `COUNTIF` function. For example, if the group *ProductX* has 10 rows, with only 8 rows having `AmountA` greater than 0, it should display a `CountA` of 8.

I already tried to add a calculated field with the formula `=IF(AmountA>0,1,0)` and then sum on this field, but it seems that the formula is applied to the grouped value, not to the actual `AmountA` for each row. For example, if the `Sum of AmountA` for the group *ProductX* is greater than 0, it will display a count of 1 (`Sum of AmountA` > 0) even if the actual count of rows having `AmountA` greater than 0 is 8.

I also considered adding new columns in the source range that would use formulas similar to `=IF(AmountA>0,1,0)`, then include them with a sum in the pivot table. However, I would like to avoid this, since I'm generically generating the source range and adapting this would require a significant amount of refactoring.

I thought about adding additional columns to the view to represent the count, but I don't think the view should be responsible of *presenting* the data; this would be a job for the report. Additionnally, I can't see how a `CountA` column would be relevant to each single row, since it either has or doesn't have an `AmountA` greater than 0.

So, is it possible to reproduce the `COUNTIF` behavior on a pivot table field, or should I consider handling the count elsewhere?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: The Excel Interop code is irrelevant to the actual problem, and I only mention it to provide context and push aside the idea of adding additional columns to the source range, due to the way I'm generating it. I'm only stating that I know it could be solved that way, but that I'm trying to find another solution before giving up. If it can't be done in the pivot table or Excel directly, I will accept the answer and refactor my own code or SQL view to work around the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resigned to hack new columns into the source range defining formulas similar to `=IF(AmountA>0,1,0)`, and then using those column with a count summary in the pivot table.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following data example:

```
AmountA AmountB AmountC
2       1       2
0       0       0
3       5       1
4       0       2
5       0       0
0       6       2
2       0       0
```

You could use the PivotTable tool "Group" to aggregate values equal 1 and higher (i.e. separating them from values equal to zero).

Set:

1. "Starting at" = 1,
2. "Ending at" = some big number (put 100 in the below example),
3. "By" = same big number from previous step.

The only problem is that you would need to create one pivot table for each variable (A,B and C).

See the below screenshot, for better understanding:

[image]

If you hide columns D, E, H and I it seems you have the desired output.